# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object') using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, formik, yup

so this is my first time use formik and Yup and i got this error while using a function:
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')

Code:

```
   import React from "react";
   import "./formikpostup.css";
   import { Formik } from "formik";
   import {Yup} from "yup";

  export default class FormikPostupload extends React.Component{
   uploadPost = Yup.object().shape({
   imageUrl: Yup.string().url().required('A url is required'),
   caption: Yup.string().max(200,'Caption has reached the maximum character limit')
   })

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="formik-upload-parent">
      <div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
   );
   } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `Yup` correctly as:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
```

Comment: ohh sorry i didnt know about that. Done :D